# Can anyone explain me in a simple word what is FND server and is it possible to make one using java?

Tags: server, webserver

Actually someone ask me to make one FND server and i don't know anything about it. I am good in java.That's why i am asking is it possible to make one in java and if it is then how ?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i am block in stackoverflow that's why i ask here.

Answer (score 2):

What it is.

> Friendly Net Detection (FND) is a technology that allows the computer to automatically recognize "friendly networks", FN in short. It is our aim to guarantee maximum security for the central data network in remote access VPNs (Virtual Private Networks) and to provide the user with secure and transparent access to the company network - no matter in which network environment the user is working.
>
> FND is a classic client / server application. The FND server (FNDS) is a separate service which is installed independent of the VPN gateway. It can be installed on any computer within the "known company network". The FND client (FNDC) is part of NCP's Secure Client Suite. It is configured within the clients firewall settings.
>
> The FND technology is based on established standards and guarantees consistent system security. Furthermore, it protects your system from errors which are frequent in proprietary solutions.
>
> Prerequisite for the use of FND is installation of FNDS in a network that has been declared as FN. This service has to be available from all ports of the network; i.e. in some cases, router settings may have to be changed.
>
> If an employee connects his end-device to the company network, the FNDC tries to contact the configured FNDS. If the device is able to contact and authenticate with the FNDS, it is confirmed that the device is within a FN. The firewall rules of the NCP Secure Client are automatically set on "internal operation".
>
> The administrator centrally sets all rules of the personal firewall, which comes as standard with the NCP Secure Client. The user can neither manipulate nor deactivate these rules.
>
> In large remote access VPN's, all templates and changes of all configuration parameter of the NCP Secure Client are ideally carried out with NCP's Secure Enterprise Management (SEM) System as "Single Point of Administration".

Like PerlDuck has said "you buy and install" not "make"! But of course you could study the architecture and design yours.

Source:

https://www.ncp-e.com/en/solutions/vpn/remote-access-vpn-technologies/friendly-net-detection/